# SQL Joins with 4 tables

Tags: sql, join

I have a problem here and I got a bit confused with outer/inner joins and multiple conditions

We have 4 tables with - columns:

1. table_cars - id | brand | type | license
2. table_equipments - id | name | description
3. table_distances - id_car | date | distance
4. table_cars_equipments - id_car | id_equipment

First query should show all cars that have equipment "fire extinguisher" and have been driving yesterday.

I have tried to write this query:

```
SELECT  table_cars_equipments.id_car
FROM    table_equipments
INNER JOIN table_cars_equipments 
    ON table_equipments.id = table_cars_equipments.id_equipment
    AND table_equipments.name LIKE 'fire extinguisher';
```

Though I am still confused how to add the cars which had been driving yesterday, I don't know how to make the connection with the table `table_distances`.

Comment: You should specify your db engine because they don't all use the same syntax to specify "yesterday".  Also, using the keyword "like" without wildcards is essentially the same as using an equal sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another `JOIN` with the table `table_cars` and another one to the table `table_distances`. Then add a condition to the `WHERE` clause to get only those cars that  have been driving yesterday. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  c.id,
  c.brand,
  c.type,
  c.license
  ce.id_car,
  ... 
from table_equipments AS e
INNER JOIN table_cars_equipments AS ce ON e.id     = ec.id_equipment 
INNER JOIN table_cars            AS c  ON c.id     = ce.id_car
INNER JOIN table_distances       AS d  ON d.id_car = c.id
WHERE e.name LIKE 'fire extinguisher'
  AND d.date = ?;
```

**Note that:** I used aliases for the table `c`, `e` etc, instead of the tables' full names.

Comment: `d.date = NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAYS` to indicate yesterday

Comment: [Mahmoud Gamal] Thank you !

Comment: @Oleksandr, if this was the resolution, please click the checkbox next to this answer so others know it is solved and no longer open.... It also helps others looking for similar problems and what DID work to fix it.

Comment: @DRapp Thank you, I am new to stackoverflow. I will know next time!

Comment: @Oleksandr, no problem... everyone starts sometime